# How to check equality of list in stream have different hashCode

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing

I want to test this method below:

```
  @override
  Stream<Either<LoadDataFailure, List<DebtPaybackItem>>> watchDebtPaybackList({
    required int personId,
    required int limit,
    DateFilter dateFilter = DateFilter.all,
  }) async* {
    try {
      yield* _database.debtPaybackList(personId, limit).watch().map((result) {
        final debtPaybackList = result.map((e) => e.toDomain()).toList();
        return right(debtPaybackList);
      });
    } on DriftWrappedException {
      yield left(const LoadDataFailure.unexpected());
    }
  }
```

The test method is:

```
 test('watchDebtPaybackList', () async {
    // Arrange
    final value = DebtPaybackData(
      id: 1,
      personId: 1,
      amount: 10,
      date: DateTime.now(),
      isDebt: 1,
    );

    when(() => mockDatabase.debtPaybackList(any(), any())).thenAnswer((_) {
      return MockSelectableData<DebtPaybackData>([value]);
    });

    // Act
    final stream = sud.watchDebtPaybackList(personId: 1, limit: 10);
    
    // Assert
    final exception = right<LoadDataFailure, List<DebtPaybackItem>>(
      [value.toDomain()],
    );

    print('$exception == $stream: ${exception.hashCode} == ${stream.hashCode}');

    expect(
      stream,
      emits(exception),
    );
  });
```

The test is always field even though the list is the same the error message is : Expected: should emit an event that Right<LoadDataFailure, List>:<Right([DebtPaybackItem(id: 1, personId: 1, amount: 10.0, note: , debtPaybackDate: 2023/05/13, isDebt: true)])>
Actual: <Instance of '_ControllerStream<Either<LoadDataFailure, List>>'>
Which: emitted * Right([DebtPaybackItem(id: 1, personId: 1, amount: 10.0, note: , debtPaybackDate: 2023/05/13, isDebt: true)])
x Stream closed.

I try to convert  it to future and using `equal` but I have the same issue, even though the data is the same It seems to have different hashcode, How can I ignore the hashcode